# Why Am I Getting an "Undefined" Return Value from Find() Using the "This" Argument?

Tags: javascript

I'm working through "Learning JavaScript" by Ethan Brown and there is an example that is not working as it should and I'm not sure what is going wrong. The section I'm working on is dealing with searching arrays with the find() method, and the particular portion that is not doing what I expect involves using the find() method with the "this" argument.

I expect this call to find(), which returns the "daniel" Person:

```
arr.find(p => p.id === daniel.id);
```

To return the same results as this call to find(), which should also return the "daniel" Person:

```
arr.find(p => p.id === this.id, daniel);
```

Instead, the first call to find works correctly, but the second returns "undefined". Why is this?

Here is the full code example (taken from Ch. 8 of Learning JavaScript - Ethan Brown):

***NOTE THIS BOOK USES ES6**

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = Person.nextId++;
  }
}

Person.nextId = 0;

const james = new Person("Jammes"),
      juliett = new Person("Juliett"),
      daniel = new Person("Daniel"),
      jay = new Person("Jay");

const arr = [james, juliett, daniel, jay];

// option 1: find daniel id by direct comparison 
// successfully returns daniel object
arr.find(p => p.id === daniel.id);

// option 2: find jay id by using "this" arg - 
// should return daniel object, instead returns undefined...
arr.find(p => p.id === this.id, daniel);
```

Comment: @4castle I'm just learning myself, but this is a good explanation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Look at [this part of that article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) inherit their lexical [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) binding from the [scope in which they are created](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions).

You can not otherwise change the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) binding of an arrow function with [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which is precisely what [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) attempts to do when you pass in a manual [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Parameters) binding.

Try using a regular function to note the difference.

```
arr.find(function (p) { return p.id === this.id; }, daniel);
```

Comment: To cite some proof, here's the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions).

Comment: @4castle Thanks. Just added a bunch of links, including that one, to the answer.

Comment: Ah OK, I was confused since I was using the arrow function as the param to another function, I wasn't sure how the scoping worked out. It's confusing for me right now!!! Thanks for "this"!

Comment: @Oka since you understand how this works, maybe submit an errata to Mr. Brown for the next edition of the book? The names he uses in the actual example are jamie, juliet, peter, and jay, I changed them for no reason...

http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920035534